# Can't get a Qt Hello World to work

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-construction

I've compiled Qt on OSX Lion using the instructions provided at [this official guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/install-mac.html). I've then tried compiling the following Hello World with `gcc hello_world.cpp -o hello_world`

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

I've got the following error:

```
hello_world.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'QApplication' file not found
#include <QApplication>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Don't you have to pass the paths to the includes and lib dirs to the compiler?

Comment: Such cryptic error messages... How is one supposed to understand what they mean?

Comment: @AdriC.S. probably that. I've never used C++ without an IDE. Any idea where those are located?

Comment: @Viclib Is there a specific reason you are not using QtCreator?

Comment: Yeah just install it and it will set paths automatically

Comment: @erelender yea I'm way more productive on VIM in general, I don't even have a mouse, so I don't think that is a good idea to use an IDE. I still have much to learn about using GCC without an IDE, though, but I'm willing to.

Comment: If you've never used C++ without an IDE before, and you don't have a mouse, how did you use C++ with an IDE before?

Comment: And if you're compiling a `C++` program you should use `g++` compiler instead.

Comment: @erelender With touchpad probably, assuming using touchpad is not productive...I don't think you can live without mouse or touchpad

Comment: As a side note, since this is supposed to be a "Hello world" example, shouldn't you at least add a line like `std::cout << "Hello world!\n"` or something like that?

Comment: OKAY GUYS! I've got it. You love Qt. That question teached me a lot and I've got it working already. But this way I don't know which of all the answers to chose!

Comment: I would vote for @erelender 's

Answer (score 3):

try instead `#include <QtGui/QApplication>`

Answer (score 3):

Use -I option of gcc to give additional include locations.

```
gcc hello_world.cpp -I/path-to-qt/include -o hello_world
```

If you use it like that, you have to use your includes like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

if you want your includes to be shorter like `#include <QApplication>`, you can give multiple include folders like this:

```
gcc hello_world.cpp -I/path-to-qt/include/QtCore -I/path-to-qt/include/QtGui -o hello_world
```

But that is not all. You also have to give library directories and which libraries to link to, which is done like this:

```
gcc hello_world.cpp -I/path-to-qt/include/QtCore -I/path-to-qt/include/QtGui -o hello_world -L/path-to-qt/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui
```

It is also better to use g++, since you are using C++.

```
g++ hello_world.cpp -I/path-to-qt/include/QtCore -I/path-to-qt/include/QtGui -o hello_world -L/path-to-qt/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the names of the libraries, they can be QtCore or QtCore4

Answer (score 2):

Try with `g++ -I<path_to_include_directory> -L<path_to_library_dir> -lQtCore`.

For example, in my Debian I would do: `g++ -I/usr/local/include/Qt4 -L/usr/local/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui whatever.cpp`

**EDIT:** Thanks to @erelender to point out that `QApplication` is in the `QtGui` library and that it depends on `QtCore`.

Comment: Also, if you use the `Qt SDK` or `QtCreator`, the IDE will probably find the correct paths for you and compile the program.

Comment: QApplication is in the QtGui library, which depends on the QtCore library.

Comment: Then it should be `-lQtCore -lQtGui` or whichever name those libs have. I think the ones I built from source don't have the version number at the end, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the path in mac, but on Linux the class QApplication
is defined at following location (qt4)

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h
```

Do you have something similar on Mac?

If you are building from command line, including a header file with gcc can be done with following switch

```
-I<path to .h file>
```

Comment: yes, I have those at `/usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h`. I'm not sure what do I tell GCC so he finds it.

Comment: use -I<path> for including .h files as a switch to gcc command line

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to add additional include path for gcc with using -I flags? Something like:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/Qt-5.1.1/include hello_world.cpp -o hello_world
```

Comment: There should be no whitespace after -I